# Checking if SQLite3 database contains any data

Tags: ios, sqlite

Setting up an SQLITE3 database as a permanent store in an app. I need to check if a database object exists populated with tables and execute an SQL DDL statement if no tables are present (i.e. on first launch of the APP)wondering if the best way to approach this is what I have below or is this completely wrong/is there a better way?! Could I just check the database property for being null/nil after the int ri = sqlite3_open_v2("schoolDatabase.db",&_database,  SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE,NULL); command or would this return a value even if the database has no tables?

```
@interface DBAccess ()
@property (nonatomic,strong) sqlite3 *database;

@implementation DBAccess
@synthesize database = _database

-(id)init

int check =sqlite3_initialise();
if(check==SQLITE_OK){
int ri = sqlite3_open_v2("schoolDatabase.db",&_database,  SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE,NULL);
if(ri==SQLITE_OK){ 
NSLOG(@"Database created successfully}; 
else{ NSLog(@"problem creating database");}

sqlite3_stmt *statement;
const char *databaseExistence = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE Type = table";
sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.database,databseExistence,-1,&statement,NULL);

while(sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW)
{
  //I am presuming column indexes are zero based in sqlite3 ?
  const unsigned char *tableNames = sqlite3_column_text(statement,2);
if(tableNames=nil){
NSLog(@"Tables in database do not exist......creating tables"
//insert SQL statement to prepare and execute CREATE TABLE commands for the Blank database
```

Comment: Your current query is probably the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [`application_id`](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_application_id) and/or [`user_version`](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_schema_version) pragmas.

If they're zero, then you've opened a new database, and can can set up your schema (and also set them to your own magic numbers). If they match your magic numbers, then the database existed. If they're nonzero but don't match, then someone changed them and you can error out early.