System.Data.SQLite: Check SQLite database is not empty (has at least one row in any table)
I need to check with System.Data.SQLite library that my SQLite database is not empty (has at least one row in any table). For now I get table names from sqlite_master table and then  query each table with SELECT * FROM [TableName] LIMIT 1.
But I search for a more optimized approach. Is it possible with a single .ExecuteQuery<T>() call?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30376595/6868726

@Kiwimanshare that code checks that database schema is clean (contains no tables). In my case tables exist and I need to check if there is any data in them.

SELECT MAX(numrows) FROM (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56326202/14171304) . Remove the DISTINCT tbl_name, part.

@dr.null Thank you. Although in my particular case this is an overkill (code in accepted answer is enough for me) - I will save your suggested code for later :)

The answer was posted before I commented but I didn't see it for some reason. (probably bad aged eyes) Yes, it's efficient enough. Good luck.

Interesting question. As far as I know there's no simple single query you can run that will do this, but you can use the ANALYZE command and the resultant sqlite_stat1 table to figure it out.
When you run ANALYZE as a non-query statement, it creates and fills the sqlite_stat1 table with some data including the row count for the table. The trick that will help solve your question is this: tables with zero rows are not listed in the output.
This gives us an option for a single-line solution that runs two statements in SQLite to give the answer you're after:
bool IsEmpty = db.SqlQuery<int>($"ANALYZE;SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_stat1").ToArray().Single() == 0;

While not pretty, and it does affect the database state, it's at least simple.
Of course the ANALYZE command does a scan of the database, so if there's a lot of data and/or indices it'll take some time.
